# How to Average only those that have a sum greater than in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, average

**How do I get the average of sum of credits for only those students with sum of credits greater than or equal to 15 credits in SQL query?**

When using HAVING (SUM(STC_ATT_CRED)) >= 15.0 it is giving me average of all the students and not just those with 15.0 or more summed credits.

```
SELECT (SUM(STC_ATT_CRED)  )/COUNT(DISTINCT stc_person_id) as 'average attempted credit',
COUNT (DISTINCT stc_person_id)         
FROM  dbo.S85_STUDENT_ACAD_CRED  
WHERE (STC_TERM='2018FA') AND ((STC_VERIFIED_GRADE IS NOT NULL ))   
AND STC_PERSON_ID IN (75 student id's in here)
HAVING (SUM(stc_att_cred)) >= 15.0
```

I expect the output to be the **average of the sum of attempted credits** for **ONLY** the 46 students **that meet the criteria (sum of attempted credits of 15 or more).**

Instead the output is giving me the average of ALL 75 students and not narrowing it down to only those that attempted a sum of 15 or more credits.

Comment: Could you add the table structure, the sample data, and your desired result, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `GROUP BY stc_person_id` to get the sum for each student and then filter the results with the condition that sum of all the student's `stc_att_cred >= 15.0` and get the average:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(t.studentsum) / COUNT(*) 'average attempted credit',
  count(*)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    stc_person_id, 
    SUM(STC_ATT_CRED) studentsum
  FROM dbo.S85_STUDENT_ACAD_CRED
  WHERE 
    STC_TERM='2018FA'
    AND 
    STC_VERIFIED_GRADE IS NOT NULL
    AND 
    STC_PERSON_ID IN (75 student id's in here)
  GROUP BY stc_person_id
) t
WHERE t.studentsum >= 15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with an inner table:

```
SELECT avg here
FROM
( 
    --Get the students and sum credits
    --Filter this list for students with sum >= 15
    SELECT STC_PERSON_ID, SUM(stc_att_cred) as studentSum     
    FROM  dbo.S85_STUDENT_ACAD_CRED  
    WHERE (STC_TERM='2018FA') AND ((STC_VERIFIED_GRADE IS NOT NULL ))  AND 
           STC_PERSON_ID IN (75 student id's in here)
    GROUP BY STC_PERSON_ID
    HAVING (SUM(stc_att_cred)) >= 15.0
)studentsWithSumCreditsOverFifteen
```